# How to use Update Select statement based on more tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have three tables such as TableA, TableB and TableC. I want to update one column in TableA from the column value in TableC. But there is no direct relationship b/w TableA and TableC. But TableB has relationship with both the tables A and C. How can I update? The structure of the tables are given below:

```
  TableA:                  TableB:               TableC:
 ----------               -----------           ----------
  ItemID                   ID                     ID
  Name                     ItemDetailID           D1
  Quantity                 TotalQty               D2
  Rate                     TotalAmount            D3 
  ItemDetailID             TotalWeight            Quantity
```

Here I want to update TableA Column "Quantity" with TableC column value "Quantity". 
I used Update select statement using two tables. But not like this. How to do? Please give suggestions...

Comment: When you said "But TableB has relationship with both the tables A and C" What is teh field name ?

Comment: No. ItemId and ID are different.

Comment: How about posting the SQL statements for your tables here as well. That would help people in instantly creating tables at their end and test what is in their mind before posting answers here.

Comment: @Ozair Kafray, Have you understood the question? It is not clear to me especially the relationship b/w tables and kindly look at the comment that I got from OP.

Comment: @SQL: No I assumed that, `A` is related to `B` by `ItemDetailID` and `B` is related to `C` by `ID`

Comment: @SQL: Yes. What Ozair said was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
Update a
set a.Quantity = c.Quantity
from TableA a
join TableB b on b.ItemDetailId = a.ItemDetailId
join TableC c on c.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update a
Set a.Quantity = c.Quantity
From TableA a
Inner Join TableB b on b.ItemDetailId = a.ItemDetailId
Inner Join TableC c on c.ID = b.ID
```